# Asp.net web config error

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nczJx.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np2mN.png

Net framework 5 was established. I installed it into the MySQL database. He faced the same mistake. How to fix it? Help please.

Server:localhost

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn 
[Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
Requiring others to take more effort in your question by referring to images won't give you much feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="named.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: Please explain why that would fix it. It may be obvious to you, but not to everyone